# INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS when trying to install APK-package

Tags: android

I'm having 2 versions of my Android application. 
One developer version and one production version. I want to install both versions on my phone.

I get this message:

```
./adb install application.apk 
1829 KB/s (177760 bytes in 0.094s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/application.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]
```

Is there any way to get around this failure without uninstall my develop version?

Comment: Interesting question. How to manage a dev version + production situation ?

Comment: Well, I have not figured out that yet :). Seems pretty heavy to change package name though. I'm requesting different API URLs in the versions - configured in a XML file. Any ideas how to do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the package in order to let android to differ your versions as package name is a unique identifier of an application.

Comment: Every time I wanna deploy in debug mode I should change the package?

Comment: of course not. Make your application have one package for debug build and another one for release. Thus you will be able to update each of them independently.

Answer (score 17):

`adb install -r InfoTest.apk` means you uninstall before install -r remove purpose 
`.//adb uninstall InfoTest.apk`

Or

Export your app with different .apk location but same signature for both.

means Version code 1.0 for dev
Version code 2.0 for production
using same keystroke file and certificate.

if you change certificates then install two apps with the same name on emulator/device.